# When focusing a window on a second display, is there are way to move the mouse as well?

Tags: display, mouse, application-switcher

I have two displays; I work on one and would like to play a game requiring some minimal interaction on the second (Loop Hero). The macOS <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> can focus the window on the second display, but the cursor remains on the first display. I want to alter the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> behavior to move the cursor whenever focusing on an application on another display. Is this possible?

For reference, I've tried Contexts hoping that <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>'ing between *windows* instead of applications would exhibit this behavior, but it doesn't. Also, I'm on Monterey if that matters.

Comment: Take a look at [this approach](https://medium.com/thevelops-tech-blog/how-to-switch-focus-between-screens-in-macos-21c6f02883a6) and see if it works for you.  If it does, comment back and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @fsb Please add it as an answer. I've also found a solution, but as I asked the question and your answer is sufficient, you deserve credit. I'll post an alternate answer afterward for future readers.

Comment: There is no order regarding answers, you can post yours anytime.

Comment: Agree with @nohillside, we want the best answers so if the solution you found works for you then you should add it whenever you want.  I'll add the one I found and hopefully they both will others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source of info](https://medium.com/thevelops-tech-blog/how-to-switch-focus-between-screens-in-macos-21c6f02883a6).

You'll need to download and install:

1. [Catch Mouse](https://github.com/round/CatchMouse/archive/master.zip)
2. Karabiner Elements (`brew cask install karabiner-elements`)

Configure:

1. Move Catch Mouse.app to Applications folder and then open it.
2. Setup your personal keyboard shortcuts for each display.  This will allow your mouse to switch displays.
3. Use Karabiner Elements to setup a keyboard shortcut that 'clicks' your mouse (to activate the display the mouse just moved to).

Then use your keyboard combination to swith displays and click the mouse.

Comment: It's worth noting that Catch Mouse coupled with AutoRaise is probably the fastest possible way to switch to an app that requires mouse focus on a second display.

Answer (score 5):

Shortly after posting my question I came across [AutoRaise](https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise). It supports warping the mouse to the center of a window selected with the application switcher and giving the window focus after a user-definable delay. The setting "AutoRaise -delay 0" will disable the focus-follows-mouse behavior and only auto-raise a window if it was switched to through the app-switcher.

(I actually forgot that I had stumbled across AutoRaise last year on an old MacBook. I got the pings of memory after posting the question and then dusted the old MB off and found it. I'm not sure why it never came up after exhausting what I thought was every way of searching for this behavior.)